# Best framework for blog management system in Vue

Tags: library, framework, vue.js

I have a task to develop a blogs management system: this system included two role (administrators and readers).
administrators can access the admin interface to (create, edit and delete blogs).
readers only access the normal interface to read blogs.
I'm working with Vuejs, so I prefer finding the suitable framework which close with Vue. Do you know the best framework for implementing my task? please share to me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: @Izzy, thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: Gladly! So will you **[edit]** your question to fill the gaps? Else you risk it being closed as "unclear" or "too broad".